# How to make fixed (portrait) screen orientation for camera in Android

Tags: screen-orientation, android-camera-intent

In android fixed screen orientation is not working on camera-intent, it's still not in fixed orientation.
applying following code but not working...

```
Intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_SCREEN_ORIENTATION, ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT)
```

Please suggest me any other way if possible.

```
            cameraIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(image));
            cameraIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_SCREEN_ORIENTATION, ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
```

startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, REQUEST_CODE);

Answer (score -1):

Android Intent's "Extra" is defined in terms of "key-value" pairs.

Here in your case; you provide value as "constant int" type which doesn't play any specific role on themselves. This constant value should be used with "setRequestedOrientation(const)" method to reflect right behaviour of the application.

There are two ways to achieve the intended implementation as you require :

1.)
 **Change screen orientation programmatically at anytime in Android**

**For Landscape mode :**
setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);

2.) 
**Change screen orientation with editing manifest file.**

You can add the permission on the manifest (for example portrait):

**uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.screen.portrait"**

Hope it would help you out.

Cheers!